# What would be the best way to pull fields from a csv?

Tags: php, html, xml, csv

I am trying to keep an .csv full of sports information. I am trying to output information from a specific field into an HTML attribute.

For example, I make a page to display James Harden's career profile. I have an excel full of information including, How many points he has scored throughout his career. I need to output his career points onto the web page, from the csv.

Could you provide topics for me to look into, or even better give me the exact stuff I need to accomplish this task? I would really appreciate it!

Edit: I am not looking to be spoon fed a solution, and am willing to learn. I do not know what to begin to search for, which is why I just now made an account to ask this.

Solutions I've found.

MySQLi: I have tried to learn how this is accomplished through a database. However the solution seems way to complicated for a simple task. Everything I have read, seems to include creating a database and fill all the CSV information just to simple print one field.

XML: I have read that XML is specifically for this. But any research attempt into it just takes me to a generator that makes a CSV file and puts it into a table. I am not looking to use a table. Just one simple field to display the 5 digit value.

I apologize if this seems like i'm being difficult but I have been searching all day and all I find is table information.

I was thinking it would be as simple as:

```
    <?php 
        $x = (a specific row for the player)
        $y = (a specific column for the statistic
        $z = x + y

        echo "Career points: </br>" . $z;
    ?>
```

Again I really apologize if I'm being difficult. I've never even experimented with tables, let alone an actual csv.

Comment: "give me the exact stuff I need" ?! What have you tried and discovered? What efforts have you made?

Comment: I have updated this and am hoping I answered your questions. I understand you may think I am lazy, but I'm just new to this whole displaying information thing and don't even understand how to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your added information indicates that you are using PHP. You could store your data in a csv file, XML file or a database such as MySQL. (A server-side Excel file should not be considered, and is [not supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) by Microsoft. Besides, your question does not suggest that you need any of Excel's functionality.)

You need to randomly access data from the source; that is, to locate and extract values for a particular identified row and column. csv is not a great choice for this as you would have to load the whole file into a data structure first, or laboriously iterate (potentially) the whole file each time you need a value. Nor can you randomly write to a location in the file.

However. csv can still be considered for a very simple file and structure, as long as you accept that you would have to parse the whole file into some data structure, and write it back again in its entirety. It is not a suitable solution for multi-user, frequent, access.

XML has similar concerns as csv, with the advantages that XML can contain detailed structured data, and can probably be more easily deserialized into PHP objects.

A database such as MySQL is the preferred option for anything other than the simplest of data stores. To get James Harden's career profile you would presumably have an EmployeeID (or similar) for him, and you would efficiently retrieve from the database just the information for this employee. Editing and writing such data is just as simple. The structure can be added to later and databases are designed for efficient, and secure, access to persistent data. There is also a HUGE amount of information available about the PHP / MySQL combination.

---

In summary, If you wish to remain with a csv file, be aware that you cannot access random locations, nor write to such locations: you need to parse the whole file into a more accessible data structure, and write the whole file if it needs editing.

Comment: And I could just import the csv into the database itself? That is exactly what I was looking for. I really thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, there will be a simple import process to get a csv into a database table.